# How do I pass a 2d array into Java Main from ReactJS?

Tags: java, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have two programs, one in ReactJS and one in Java, and need to pass a 2d array from ReactJS into my Java main, but didn't realise that I can't modify the main signature of `public static void main(String[] args) {}` to accept it.

I've seen similar questions around, but they are mostly about passing multidimensional arrays around methods in general which are setup inside of the method, but need to pass in something like:

`[["1", "string", "1.0"], ["2", "string", "2.0"]]`

...but can't be sure what I need to get out. It'll only add to the string elements in the middle, so will be something like:

`[["1", "string", "string", "1.0"], ["2", "string", "string", "string", "2.0"]]`

So, just to reiterate, how can I pass in a 2d array (knowing how big the internal array will be), and return a 2d array (not knowing how big the internal arrays will be)?

My Java class is as follows...

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * This class takes a parameter (review) through the main args and runs it through the sentiment analysis.
 * Where necessary, the analysis breaks the review into shorter sentences and scores each one.
 * If devMode is set to TRUE, the detailed output is displayed in the console.
 * The average of the review sentiments are then returned as a type double.
 */
public class SentimentAnalysis {

    private static ArrayList findSentiment(ArrayList<String[]> allReviews) {
        // Set to TRUE to display the breakdown of the output to the console
        boolean devMode = false;

        ArrayList<List> scoredReviewsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        double totalSentimentScore = 0;
        int counter = 1;

        // Setup Stanford Core NLP package
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        if (devMode) {
            System.out.println("" +
                    "\n==============================================================================================================\n" +
                    "The output shows the sentiment analysis for the comment provided.\n" +
                    "The StanfordCoreNlp algorithm breaks apart the input and rates each section numerically as follows:\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\t1 = Negative\n" +
                    "\t2 = Neutral\n" +
                    "\t3 = Positive\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "The returned value is the average of all the sentiment ratings for the provided comment.\n" +
                    "==============================================================================================================\n"
            );
        }

        for (String[] singleReview : allReviews) {
            ArrayList<String> review = new ArrayList<>();
            String reviewId = singleReview[0];
            review.add(reviewId);

            double sentimentSectionScore;

            String reviewText = singleReview[1];

            if (reviewText != null && reviewText.length() > 0) {

                Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(reviewText);

                for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                    Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);

                    sentimentSectionScore = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);

                    totalSentimentScore += sentimentSectionScore;

                    if (devMode) {
                        System.out.println("\nSentence " + counter++ + ": " + sentence);
                        System.out.println("Sentiment score: " + sentimentSectionScore);
                        System.out.println("Total sentiment score: " + totalSentimentScore);
                    }

                    review.add(sentence.toString());
                    review.add(String.valueOf(sentimentSectionScore));
                }

                scoredReviewsArray.add(review);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(scoredReviewsArray.toString());

        return scoredReviewsArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Test array of review arrays
        String mockReview1[] = {"1", "String 1.1. String 1.2.", ""};
        String mockReview2[] = {"2", "String 2", ""};
        String mockReview3[] = {"3", "String 3", ""};
        ArrayList<String[]> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        reviews.add(mockReview1);
        reviews.add(mockReview2);
        reviews.add(mockReview3);

        findSentiment(reviews);

    }
}
```

...and I'm wrapping up my Java application into a Jar to pass in and retrieve the data from ReactJS using a child process, as follows:

```
const exec = require('child_process').spawn('java', ['-jar', './StanfordNlp.jar', allReviews]);

    exec.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        // Do stuff...
    });
```

Hope this all makes sense, if you need me to clarify anything, please just ask.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered "JSON in, JSON out"?

Comment: @GordThompson JSON would be great, but I've never used them in Java, seems a little long winded, no?

Comment: re: "long winded" - Could be worse. Could be XML.

Comment: @GordThompson: Ha, yes, I suppose... any ideas on how I may work this out?

Comment: How is a React program (presumably in the browser) supposed to communicate with a CLI Java application? The usual approach is to run a Web server (Spring Boot, Dropwizard) and communicate through HTTP and JSON.

Comment: @chrylis: I'm wrapping the Java up into a Jar and using a child process to pass data in and retrieve it. See my updated answer.